# Use single struct / trait with implementation for two types

Tags: rust

I want to implement a generic way to use redis as a cluster or as a single node. It will have some specific functions to `redis::Client` and specific functions to `redis::cluster::ClusterClient`.

```
pub struct Redis<T> {
    client: T
}

pub trait RedisClient {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

impl RedisClient for Redis<redis::Client> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Redis {
            client: redis::Client::open("some_url").unwrap()
        }
    }
}

impl RedisClient for Redis<redis::cluster::ClusterClient> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Redis {
            client: redis::cluster::ClusterClient::open(["some_url"].to_vec()).unwrap()
        }
    }
}
```

But most of the functions are shared. How do I implement for both types at the same time? I would like to use it like this:

```
impl Redis<some_Type to accomodate both> {
    pub fn set(&self) {}
    pub fn get(&self) {}
}
```

so that I do not have to rewrite identical functionality twice like so:

```
impl Redis<redis::Client> {
    pub fn set(&self) {}
    pub fn get(&self) {}
}

impl Redis<redis::cluster::ClusterClient> {
    pub fn set(&self) {}
    pub fn get(&self) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following way should work if I understand your problem correctly. Give it a try.

```
impl<T> Redis<T> {
    pub fn set(&self) {}
    pub fn get(&self) {}
}
```

Comment: How would I access `client` though without having to do something like `std::mem::transmute`? because T will not be defined in those functions

Comment: You should simply add a trait bound to the `impl`, like `impl<T: RedisClient> Redis<T> {…}`. The `RedisClient` trait should abstract all differences between the two clients, and all the common code can go in the `Redis` impl.